# Tree data ag-Grid and Angular 4

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

The example provide in the link seems to be a JavaScript one -
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree/?framework=angular#gsc.tab=0.

Can this be integrated with Angular?
What are the tings taken care of in warping up in angular interface using ag-Grid?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. ag-grid is a grid that was designed for Angular, and yes, the example code will work. Use of of their examples to get it up and running, and then modify it for your own purposes

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation for ag-Grid, it shows how to get the grid integrated with angular.

[ag-Grid Angular 2](https://www.ag-grid.com/best-angular-2-data-grid/)

All the features work in Angular 2 - the examples for the different features are in JavaScript only because the grid supports so many frameworks, the team would find it impossible to demonstrate every feature in every framework.